# Локальный сервер на Ubuntu

Tags: сервер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, локальный сервер, на Убунту, по типу Денвера.

Comment: Не знаю, кто минусовал. Мне так вопрос понравился. Если стартёр топика ответит на вопрос, что есть денвер, то данный вопрос будет снят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamp

Comment: sudo apt-get install lamp-server^

Answer (score 3):

Apache, nginx

Comment: ну мне надо, что-бы там была поддержка php

Comment: @Zow, epic facepalm. В Апаче нет PHP поддержки что ли?

Comment: @Construct - @Zow из товрисчей которые хотят творить "великие" весЧи не прикладывая для этого должных усилий ( которые, к тому-же, где-то, считают всех программистов унылым гавном, мол ничего они не умеют, все, что они делают легко и т.д. ). Для тех, кому не совсем плевать - просто тупо игнорьте :)

Comment: Алекс, я что-то тебя не понял.

Comment: @mikillskegg - это из опыта общения с "пациентом" :)

Comment: Кажется, назревает драма...

Comment: @karmadro4 - в чем-же? :)

Comment: а, ну ладно. только без крайностей, пожалуйста.